# OpenCart 3.0.2.0 - force SSL and fix "www" .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, opencart

I am working on a fresh install that runs on OpenCart 3.0.2.0.

I bought a SSL certificate and my host activated it. I then proceeded to activate SSL from OpenCart's admin (System->Settings->Server->Use SSL) and, after editing the config file, it works as intended by OpenCart (only on the pages that have forms).

However, I want the ceritificate to be visible on all pages.

Besides, OpenCart has some problems when typing the URL of the website with "www" before the domain name that causes font-awesome icons to not load. I could edit the config.php file and add the "www" in there but that would mess up the URL without the "www".

Figured out that the only way to force SSL on all pages AND fix the "www" problem as well is to edit my .htaccess file.

I tried adding this to force SSL on all pages with no results:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uneltescu\.ro [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://uneltescu.ro/$1 [R,L]
```

Looked over the internet and SO and found multiple variants of forcing SSL and the "www" version to work properly but none of them seemed to work for me, maybe I didn't understood what they were aimed to achieve correctly.

This is how my default .htaccess file looks:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

How should a complete, working .htaccess look like for OC 3.0.2.0 to force SSL and fix the "www" problem?

Would be nice if the code would not include my website's URL and generally work for any OC 3.0.2.0 installation so that it can further be used by the community without any further tweaking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix it. Here's how I did it:

Right under the comment after `RewriteEngine On` I added the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This seems to redirect both the www and non www version to https://domain-name.com

---

If you want to redirect the non-www to the www version then you need to replace this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
```

With this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
```

And make sure the lines where the redirect takes place include the "www" like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note: Make sure to specify the www or non-www URL in your website's config files located in the public_html and admin folders according to preference.

---

In order to make it work for all links I had to open the config.php file located in my public_html folder and change my domain name to include https everywhere (including in the first HTTP section).

However, when I tried to access my admin page via SSL my CSS wasn't displayed. Fixed this by editing the config.php file that is in the admin folder in the same way. Didn't had to change it for both HTTPS and HTTP. I just changed it in the HTTPS section to include `https://`

Here's the .htaccess that you can copy and paste (make a backup of your own first).

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: This looks really helpful, i am on trying to set up an opencart site for my wife at present and have an SSL cert but when you go to any page after the home page the ssl stops  working. Will this fix this?